# Using the GEPlugin KmlCamera from c#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-earth-plugin

I am able to get the Google Earth Plugin to work in my C# windows form - but I wish to ask about getting the "camera" to turn the globe to a lat and long that I supply.

Does anyone knows which method to call, or if there is an article on using C# to control google earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library of controls I have created to work with the Google Earth Api from managed code.

http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

The library allows you to use the api just as you would in javascript- it also has helper functions to create objects, and work with events, in the api easily.

FYI, to set up and use a camera you would do something like so.

```
// where ge is an instance of GEPlugin.
var camera = ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// set latitude and longitude
camera.setLatitude(36.584207);
camera.setLongitude(-121.754322);

// for a list of all the KmlCamera members see:
// http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_camera.html

// update the view
ge.getView().setAbstractView(camera);
```

But I would suggest using the library!